# Set config item (csrf) doesnt work in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, config, csrf

I want to turn ON csrf protection only in a few of my controllers, so I have

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');        
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model('user_model', '', true);

    $this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', TRUE);

}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, although when I do var_dump($this->config) on a page it shows that csrf_protection is TRUE, but the cookies are not set and the form has a hidden field without value

`<input type="hidden" name="ci_csrf_token" value="" />`

Csrf token name and cookie name are all set, the forms are called with form_open().

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:** So this is not possible from version 2.1.1 because of the line in security class construct `if (config_item('csrf_protection') === TRUE) {`

Security class is initialized before the controller, so its natural that the config item change in the controller will not affect it.

Comment: Try setting the config item BEFORE loading the form helper?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast answer, unfortunately that did not solve the problem, i've put the set_item right after parent::construct

Comment: CSRF protection is part of core and is initialized well before any of your controllers are processed. If you want to do this and you are running CI 2.x, you may have to modify core with a `MY_Security.php` file in `application/core` and provide your logic in there to apply CSRF to specific Controllers. You want to read [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) and examine the file `system/core/Security.php` If you are running CI 3.x it has a new config item `$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();` which will do just what you want. But it's only in CI 3.x

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The problem is, is that I know that it should work. On a couple of my other projects it works perfectly, I set csrf_protection to false, and turn it on with set_item on specific pages. I will modify my core files temporarily until I find a working solution

Ok never mind. I found out that in my other project the security class construct does not have the line `if (config_item('csrf_protection') === TRUE)`

It must have been added in later versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a solution for you. Create a custom application/core/MY_Security.php and put this in it:

```
<?php if ( !defined( 'BASEPATH' ) ) exit( 'No direct script access allowed' );

class MY_Security extends CI_Security
{
    public function csrf_verify( )
    {
        foreach ( config_item('csrf_excludes') as $exclude )
        {
            $uri = load_class('URI', 'core');
            if ( preg_match( $exclude, $uri->uri_string() ) > 0 )
            {
                // still do input filtering to prevent parameter piggybacking in the form
                if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]) && preg_match( '#^[0-9a-f]{32}$#iS', $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name] ) == 0)
                {
                    unset( $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name] );
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        parent::csrf_verify( );
    }
}
```

This will check the following excludes which you need to put in your application/config.php in the CSRF section:

```
$config['csrf_excludes'] = array
    ( '@^/?excluded_url_1/?@i'
    , '@^/?excluded_url_2/?@i' );
```

Every matching URL pattern will be excluded from CSRF checks. You can build regex here at http://rubular.com

cheers

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I did exactly that.

I copied the security class of CI 3.0 to MY_security class,because it already has the option to turn off CSRF protection for specific urls with $config['csrf_exclude_uris'], it was an easier solution for future migration to CI 3.0. But your solution is also nice, thanks!