# CodeIgniter use CSRF protection only in some pages

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, csrf

What I want to do is to protect some sensitive forms from `CSRF` attack in `codeigniter` but not all pages.

To protect from `CSRF` if I set it in config.php it applies for all pages. is there any way to do that only for some pages by setting in controller?

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: This feature has been implemented in CI 3.0-DEV, If you're using v2.x of CI, take a look at this answer and give it a try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860653/1725764

Comment: @HashemQolami thanks, please leave it as answer to accept.

Comment: IMHO, posing an exact answer is not a good treat, it'll be duplicate content. I posted the link of a similar question which should remain as the reference.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this by editing the `config.php` file

```
 $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

Step 1:  create an array of pages that you want to protect

eg. `$csrf_pages = array('login','test');`

Step2: check if there is any request for the protected page then set it to TRUE;

```
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    foreach ($csrf_pages as $csrf_page){
        if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],$csrf_page) !== FALSE) {
            $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Step 3:  add this to your views

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>" />
```

Or simply use the form_open() function to add the hidden CSRF token field automatically.

Comment: I used this for $config['csrf_regenerate'] instead and also the other way around so that the default is true and I only disable it for my ajax pages. It's not good to disable CSRF but turning off the regen is a working fix.

Answer (score 12):

Now the CI3 have this feature, we can exclude the URIs in the config
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('api/person/add');


$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
    'api/record/[0-9]+',
    'api/title/[a-z]+'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more safer approach, you should switch on CSRF protection at all times and only exempt some pages you wish in an array in the config.php file.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

Then set an array of links you wish to exempt from CSRF protection:

```
$csrf_off = array(
    "/api",
    "/api/example",
    "/somelink/something/example"
    );
```

Now turn those array links CSRF protection off.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    if (in_array($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],$csrf_off)) {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```