# ERROR While enabling CSRF protection TRUE in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form in my application, I need to add `csrf_protection = TRUE` in my `config.php` for security reason. But after adding this my form can not submit and show me an error like this.

```
An Error Was Encountered
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

Can anyone tell me, How to fix this?

Below is CSRF code in my config.php

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

Comment: Is the CSRF token in your form? If you use CI's `form_open()` it automatically adds it. Otherwise, you can manually add it with `<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />`. [See here.](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on CSRF then make sure that you use form_open function to open form tag otherwise you will see error which you're getting.

Here are related links to this information - 

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html 

[Codeigniter CSRF - how does it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244669/codeigniter-csrf-how-does-it-work)

[CodeIgniter use CSRF protection only in some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378688/codeigniter-use-csrf-protection-only-in-some-pages)