# How to disable CSRF validation for hmvc folder only in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using **$config['csrf_protection'] = true;** in config and it is working perfectly.

I am using HMVC. But I want to disable csrf protection for all controllers present in the modules folder.

like for folder

```
./modules/app_one
........./app_one/controllers

./modules/app_two
........./app_two/controllers
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter use CSRF protection only in some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378688/codeigniter-use-csrf-protection-only-in-some-pages)

Comment: please read question again i want to disable it on whole module of hmvc